# What is the maximum input length (if any) for sha2 in Azure Databricks?

Tags: azure-databricks

If any, is there a limitation to the length of the `expr` parameter in the sha2 function?

Example: `SELECT sha2('very_long_concatenated_string', 512)`

Is there a maximum length for `'very_long_concatenated_string'`? Ideally, this could be checked with len(`'very_long_concatenated_string'`). I need to know this to be sure the input string will not be truncated.

A similar question is being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986028/sha-512-length-of-the-input-string-impact), but I require confirmation for the Databricks implementation.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/sha2

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the `sha2` function with a string of length 400,000,000 and it has successfully generated the result. I have used code as shown below:

```
s= 'q'*400000000
q=f"SELECT sha2('{s}', 512) as ans"
display(spark.sql(q))
```

[image]

- If string length is too long then it is throwing `MemoryError` and other errors like kernal is unresponsive.
- But there might be no way if the string is getting truncated in the process. In general, there might not be any string length limit for `sha2` function atleast upto 500,000,000 length string.

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution. How do you know the input is not truncated?

Comment: There might be no way to understand this. There is no way to de-hash the result produced so that it can be compared with the input string. So, it is hard to tell with certainty that input is not truncated.